# Аннотации в Java медленнее, чем XML-файлы конфигурации?

Tags: java

Относительно недавно в Java появились аннотации, способные заменить ненавистные всеми XML-файлы. В обычных условиях я бы никогда не задался этим вопросом, но так как свой проект я держу на Google App Engine, в котором из-за Loading-request счет идет на миллисекунды.
Я всячески оптимизировал код, чтоб сделать его максимально быстрым (в первую очередь избавился от JDO в пользу Low-level API), но я где-то читал мнение, что аннотации тоже снижают быстродействие приложения.
Аннотации в Java медленнее, чем XML-файлы конфигурации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что значит медленее? Медленнее для чего? В какой момент медлененее? Вы имеете в виду медленнее для чтения? С некоторой точки зрения может и медленнее, а с другой - быстрее.

**UPD**

По идее разницы быть не должно. Но при старте сервера для поиска аннотаций серверу надо обходить все классы и искать в них аннотации, в то время как пропарсить один XML проще. С другой стороны, это может потребоваться только один раз при старте сервера, так что эта разница в скорости не имеет значения. К сожалению, ничего не могу сказать о жизненном цикле бинов в GAE.

Comment: Медленнее в инициализации. Например, bean, размеченный аннотацией @ManagedBean и @SessionScoped, и bean, информация о котором записана в XML файле (<managedbean>...</managedbean>). Какому из этих классов потребуется больше времени на инициализацию?

Comment: Если приложение не посещалось 5 минут, оно автоматически выгружается из памяти. При первом за 5 минут обращении стартует новая VM, называемая instanse - это в их терминологии называется Loading request. Получается аннотации в GAE могут увеличивать длительность этого самого Loading requestа.

Answer (score 1):

Медленне происходит deploy приложения. Впрочем если сервер приложения не настроен иначе, сканирование на наличие аннотаций происходит в любом случае.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос скудный т.к аннотации могут в некоторой степени увеличивать свою скорость из-за прописи строк во внутренностях самой той или иной аннотации, чего просто не найти в XMLе, т.к что на вопрос ответить немного трудновато